# Excel Macro to open up the Visual Basic Editor

Tags: excel, vba, editor

After completing a macro that opens when an Excel Workbook is opened (I'm sort of using a workbook as a makeshift executable in this sense), I then have a Messagebox appear and ask the user if they need to modify/look at the code, or if they are finished. If they're finished, it simply closes, but if they would like to look at the code they must then open up the Visual Basic Editor manually. This is fine, but it would be nice and smooth if it would simply pop up on it's own if they choose that option. Is there any function that opens the Editor window?

Comment: `Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True`. If you want to show a paritcular module, e.g. `Module1`, you can add: `Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("Module1").Activate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub ShowVBE()
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Respectfully, I think this is a bad answer. See my answer below for why.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that doesn't require the user to reduce their security settings (I agree completely with the comment by pgSystemTester) and works for any UI language the user is using (the solution by pgSystemTester will not work for all language UI settings eg in Spanish the keys would be "%gv") is to use the relevant CommandBarButton for the VBE.

```
Sub OpenTheVbe()
    Dim isEnabled As Boolean
    ' where 21 is the "Visual Basic" CommandBar and 4 is the "Visual Basic Editor" CommandBarButton
    With Application.CommandBars(21).Controls(4)
        isEnabled = .Enabled
        .Enabled = True
        .Execute
        .Enabled = isEnabled
    End With
End Sub
```

This solution then doesn't have the usual problems with the use of `SendKeys` and works for any UI language that the user is using.

Answer (score 1):

The [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68322015/11732320) requires the user ***to reduce their security settings***.  I would strongly question a decision to reduce the overall security of the operating system simply so that a user can create a convenience macro that's essentially a shortcut.  It's also worth noting that such a macro/shortcu already exists in the Excel Application -- the icon exists on the developer tab, but one could find it and place that same icon in the Quick Access Tool Bar or typing `alt L V`

If one *still* insists on making their own macro, see [my answer here proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72222962/11732320) on a duplicate question,

```
Application.SendKeys ("%lv")
```

Even though I'm personally not a fan of computer keystroke macros, in this case it makes sense considering the macro already was built by Microsoft...

Note that you could try `ALT`+`F11` (`"%{F11}`) but make sure the keyboard has the function buttons (`F1-F9` or higher) being activated on being pressed -- NOT a modifier  (i.e. the `FUNCTION` key itself, which is probably confusing). Stated differently,  you can open the VBE editor with either `ALT`+`F11` or `FUNCTION_BUTTON`+`ALT`+`F11`.